# Localizable.strings compiled twice?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios, xcode4

when I switch from xcode3 to xode4, I have found that, for several strings there in the App, I have to compile it twice in order to make it localized ...
Anyone ever has the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happen when the strings file is referenced twice in the "Resources" build phase. Xcode will not warn you when this happens, and it may cause strange or undefined behavior. Look through all your build phases and make sure the file is in only one place.

Comment: I have my localizable.strings file referenced only once, but another localizable.strings file from the sharekit framework that I have in my project has a localizable.strings file as well. Can't remove them

Comment: You might try renaming one of the Localizable.strings files to something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the case like me, that you have two Localizable.strings files (because you are using some additional framework(s) (like ShareKit) that use Localizable.strings file(s) themselves) then you can also do the following:

1. Rename the additional `Localizable.strings` file(s) to sth. like `RenamedFile.strings` so that in the end there is <= 1 Localizable.strings file.
2. Search and replace all occurrences 
   `NSLocalizedString(key, description);`
   related to the RenamedFile.strings with
   `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, @"RenamedFile", description);`

**Example:** 
Lets say you have
(A) your own Localizable.strings file
(B) and a Localizable.strings file cause you use ShareKit which has it's own localizations as well.

1. Rename `Localizable.strings` of ShareKit to `ShareKit.strings`
   (using Git and Xcode 4 I had some problems renaming the files, but it was solvable).
2. Look for all the occurrences of NSLocalizedString in the ShareKit folder (should be 3) and replace them:

   - `NSLocalizedString(key, key);`
     -> `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, @"ShareKit", key);`
   - `NSLocalizedString(@"Disconnect from Facebook", @"Accessibility label");`
     -> `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Disconnect from Facebook", @"ShareKit", @"Accessibility label");`
   - `NSLocalizedString(@"Connect to Facebook", @"Accessibility label");`
     -> `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Connect to Facebook", @"ShareKit", @"Accessibility label");`